# Как найти самую большую разницу между значениями массива?

Tags: javascript

```js
// пример
var arr = [12.32, 10.22, 103.325, 9.02, 0.99, 57.1, 42, 11.025];
```

В результате нужно получить 2 ключа массива этих значений

Из примера выше это будет:
`arr[2]`
`arr[4]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам просто нужно найти индексы минимального и максимального значений:

```js
// пример
var arr = [12.32, 10.22, 103.325, 9.02, 0.99, 57.1, 42, 11.025];
var res = arr.reduce((r, el, i, ar) => {
  if (typeof r.min == "undefined" || ar[i] < ar[r.min])
    r.min = i;
  if (typeof r.max == "undefined" || ar[i] > ar[r.max])
    r.max = i;
  return r;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Тоже так думал сделать через Math, но только не понял как получить ключи в массиве этих значений. Можно как то связать с вашим примером вот такой вариант `arr.indexOf('0.99');`? вроде как должен получать индекс в массиве этого значения

Comment: @Bert А-а-а, Вам индексы нужны?

Comment: да, как раз то что нужно, спасибо

Comment: Да уж, старые добрые циклы уже никому не нужны... :)

Comment: `let max = 0, min = 0; for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) { if (arr[max] < arr[i]) max = i; if (arr[min] > arr[i]) min = i; } console.log(min, max);` читается куда проще и не нужны никакие лишние проверки на `undefined`. Хотя я понял, ваша задача — как можно сильнее запутать код, чтобы вроде как и помочь нерадивому студенту, но по факту он не понял как это работает и не смог отчитаться преподавателю...

Comment: @АндрейNOP проверку на `undefined` можно исключить если определить min&max в аккумуляторе

Comment: @Bald, ок, какие, например, значения установить в качестве начальных? Но в общем, идею с тем, что здесь надо использовать `reduce` вы поддерживаете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Number.MAX_VALUE для минимума и наоборот

Comment: @АндрейNOP ---так же как и в вашем ответе(0)---, выше предложили даже лучше, а почему бы и нет. тот же цикл

Comment: @Bald, можно, почему нет. Будет на одну проверку больше, но на сложность (O) это, конечно, не влияет. Основная моя претензия здесь вообще к использованию `reduce`, анонимных функций и прочего, в чем здесь нет нужды. С другой стороны, любое решение полезно и хорошо знать все возможные. Свой вариант я предложил, что выберет автор — его дело. (автор вообще планировал жуквери прикрутить, судя по метке)

Comment: @АндрейNOP если в ответе Igor, в аккумуляторе min&max определить явно, то код будет *идентичен* вашему(проверка на undefined будет не нужна же), только с использованием фишек из более поздних стандартов

Comment: @Bald, будет на одну итерацию больше, т.к. reduce перебирает все элементы, а я с индекса 1, но это не принципиально

Comment: @АндрейNOP `жуквери` люблю это название, вспомнилось это https://external-preview.redd.it/bOS7PlmOBhuR3aDTDcqsSLmh_He57vxr_d-zZoYoUO4.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e9076683613037db725cdf50a730b6a8000993f5

Answer (score 5):

Просто используйте *циклы*:

```js
var arr = [ 12.32, 10.22, 103.325, 9.02, 0.99, 57.1, 42, 11.025 ];
let max = 0, min = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  if (arr[max] < arr[i]) max = i;
  if (arr[min] > arr[i]) min = i;
}
console.log(min, max);
```

Comment: а если вы *пропускаете* первый элемент(*будет на одну итерацию больше, т.к. reduce перебирает все элементы, а я с индекса 1*), то тогда может min/max инициализировать первым элементом массива? или я что то не понял?

Comment: @Bald, ага именно так и сделал: `let max = 0, min = 0;`

Comment: смотрю код... не понимаю... я имел ввиду `let max = arr[0];`, а вы инициализируете **0**

Comment: @Bald, всё верно, смотрите в теле цикла как эти значения используются. Это *индексы* минимального и максимального значений. Наверное, плохо переменные названы просто

Answer (score 3):

А может так?

```js
let a = [12.32, 10.22, 103.325, 9.02, 0.99, 57.1, 42, 11.025]
let max = Math.max(...a);
let min = Math.min(...a);
let minIndex = a.indexOf(min);
let maxIndex = a.indexOf(max);

console.log(maxIndex, minIndex)
```

Функции математических операторов [min](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) и [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) могут быть вызваны для n аргументов

Конечно кол-во аргументов имеет ограничение, однако много когда это подойдет

Comment: ТС вроде как индексы минимального/максимального хочет, но это не точно

Comment: @АндрейNOP  еще 2 раза indexOf?

Comment: Самый понятный и читаемый код. Но и самый медленный.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Все верно, каждый выберет себе тот, который ему нужен :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а еще и кол-во аргументов ограничено, однако это все лирика по отношению к читаемости, ряде случаев

Comment: Да, если данный код не будет запускаться на 10000+ элементов или\и в методе, который выполняется 100+ раз в секунду - то я предпочту его)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const findMinMaxElements = (arr) =>{
    
    let minIndex = 0;
    let maxIndex = 0;

    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){                
        if(arr[minIndex] > arr[i+1]) minIndex = i+1;    
        if(arr[maxIndex] < arr[i+1]) maxIndex = i+1;                
    }

    return {
        minIndex: minIndex,
        maxIndex: maxIndex
    }
}

console.log(findMinMaxElements([20, 3, 1, -4, 12, 0]));
```

Comment: Для чего строчка ``if( i == arr.length) break;``?

Comment: Чтобы завершить цикл

Comment: А что делает ``i < arr.length;`` в инициализации цикла?

Comment: Эникейщик, мне интересно, а возможно ли решить эту задачу используя рекурсию?

Answer (score 0):

Пусть тогда уже будет и вариант с рекурсией)

```js
var arr = [12.32, 10.22, 103.325, 9.02, 0.99, 57.1, 42, 11.025];

const find = (arr, i = 1, max = 0, min = 0) => {
  if (i === arr.length) return [max, min];
  
  if (arr[i] > arr[max]) max = i;
  if (arr[i] < arr[min]) min = i;
  
  return find(arr, ++i, max, min);
}

console.log(find(arr));
```